# How to make DIV tag of flash notice to stay in view always?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have implemented flash notice in my ROR website, wherein a notice is displayed through jQuery. It will be changed every 5 seconds. Another notice will slidedown.

```
<div class="interactive_text">
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
</div>
```

Now the issue is, as the DIV tag is not in view all the time, as i scroll down the browser window or when this notice is too close to footer, this notice DIV slides down every 5 seconds dragging down rest of DIV tags below it. It compromises user experience of website. How to make this DIV tag to stay in view all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting Position:"fixed" for the div